# SolidJS: Updating component based on value served by Context's store?

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

In React all props are updated and propagated to children automatically which is nice but it slows down and requires lots of optimization at some point.

So I'm building an app with SolidJS using `Context` + `createStore` patterng and I'm having problems with consuming that state.

I'd like to create `AppProvider` component that manages `State` props and `Dispatch` functions. The Provider will be performing all operations on `appStore`, implement functions and serve them all via `AppContextState` and `AppContextDispatch` providers.

Then I need to consume that data to update components that are dependent on it reactively.

Look at the code below:

```
/// index.tsx
import { render } from 'solid-js/web';
import { AppProvider } from '@/providers/AppProvider';
import App from './App';


render(() => (
    <AppProvider>
        <App />
    </AppProvider>
), document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
```

```js
/// AppProvider.tsx
import { createContext, useContext, JSX } from 'solid-js';
import { createStore } from 'solid-js/store';

// Interfaces
interface IAppState {
    isConnected: boolean;
    user: { name: string; }
}
interface IAppDispatch {
    connect: () => Promise<void>;
    disconnect: () => Promise<void>;
}


// Initialize
const initialState = {
    isConnected: false,
    user: { name: '' }
}
const initialDispatch = {
    connect: () => {},
    disconnect: () => {}
}


// Contexts
const AppContextState = createContext<IAppState>();
const AppContextDispatch = createContext<IAppDispatch>();
export const useAppState = () => useContext(AppContextState);
export const useAppDispatch = () => useContext(AppContextDispatch);

// Provider
export const AppProvider = (props: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
    const [appStore, setAppStore] = createStore<IAppState>(initialState);

    async function connect() {
        setAppStore("isConnected", true);
        setAppStore("user", "name", 'Chad');
    }

    async function disconnect() {
        setAppStore("isConnected", false);
        setAppStore("user", "name", '');
    }

    return (
        <AppContextState.Provider value={appStore}>
            <AppContextDispatch.Provider value={{ connect, disconnect }}>
                {props.children}
            </AppContextDispatch.Provider>
        </AppContextState.Provider>
    )
}
```

```
/// App.tsx
import { useAppState, useAppDispatch } from '@/providers/AppProvider';

export default function App() {
    const { user, isConnected } = useAppState();
    const { connect, disconnect } = useAppDispatch();

    return (
      <Show when={isConnected} fallback={<button onClick={connect}>Connect</button>}>
        <button onClick={disconnect}>Disconnect</button>
        <h3>Your Name: {user.name}</h3>
      </Show>
    )
}
```

This component will show a `button` that should run the `connect` function and update `isConnected` state and make the component within `<Show>` block visible but it doesn't do anything.

I verified that state is being updated by logging data of *appStore* in *connect* method.

When I change the component to depend on `user.name` instead `isConnected` it works

```js
<Show when={user.name} fallback={<button onClick={connect}>Connect</button>}>
    <button onClick={disconnect}>Disconnect</button>
    <h3>Your Name: {user.name}</h3>
</Show>
```

However my app has many components depending on various data types, including `boolean` that for some doesn't work in this example with SolidJS.

I'd like to know what am I doing wrong here and understand what is the best way to share state between components. I keep reading documentation and fiddling with it but this particular problem bothers me for a past few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plain Values in Solid cannot be tracked

The problem here is that primitive values / variables cannot be reactive in solid. We have two ways of tracking value access: Through function calls, and through property getters/proxies (which use signals under the hood).

So, what happens when you access a store property?

```js
const state = useAppState();
createEffect(() => {
  console.log(state.isConnected)
})
```

In this case, the property access is occurring within the effect, so it gets tracked, and reruns when the property value updates. On the other hand, with this:

```js
const { isConnected } = useAppState();
```

We are accessing the property at the top level of the component (which is `untrack`ed and not reactive in solid). So even though we use this value in a context that is reactive (like the `when` prop in `), we can't run any special under-the-hood tracking to set up updates.

#### So why did `user.name` work?

The reason is that stores are deeply reactive (for primitives, objects and arrays), so

```js
const { user } = useAppState();
```

Means that you are eagerly accessing the user object (so if the user property changes, you won't get updated), but the *properties of* the user object were not accessed yet, they only get accessed further on, in `<Show when={user.name}>`, so the property access `user.name` is able to be tracked.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for answering! Now I understand that properties are reactive as long as they are not directly accessed/destructured but rather accessed through the parent object. It all works now as expected.

Comment: generally, destructuring is an anti-pattern in solidjs